# Display Array in Listbox

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    lstPatientNames.Items.Add(Names())

End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to have the list box display the array: names(). However I get the error: "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array". The array does not have a set number of elements as the user decides the amount of elements for the array when entering data. So how should my code look?

Thanks

Filling the Array:

```
Public Class Form2

Dim i As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPatient.Click


    ReDim Preserve Names(0 To i)
    Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text

    ReDim Preserve Heights(0 To i)
    Heights(i) = txtPatientHeight.Text

    ReDim Preserve Weights(0 To i)
    Weights(i) = txtPatientWeight.Text

    i = i + 1

    Label1.Text = i

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: show me code for your array..i mean where it is filled out.

Comment: I think you will need to loop through each Name in Names and add individually.

Comment: I will try a loop, I think that is how I managed to solve a similar problem I just forgot how Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List1.Items.Clear
List1.Items.AddRange(al1.ToArray)
```

OR,

```
List1.Items.Clear
For each obj as object in al1
    List1.Items.Add(obj)
Next
```

Or,

```
List1.Items.Clear
For i as Integer = 0 to al1.count-1
    List1.Items.Add(al1(i))
Next
```

You will have to override the ToString of your object in the Arraylist. You will have to make the listbox font a fixed font so you can do the spacing (Courier New).
I would suggest using a Generic.List (Of clsCustomer) however if that's not in the assignment you'll be stuck typecasting the objects in the arraylist.
This still leaves out a ton of detail for solving that assignment, however.
Good luck.

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355655/how-do-i-put-an-arraylist-in-a-listbox)

Comment: al1 seems to give me an error when I enter your first option, is that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: @Marcel al1 is actualy ArrayList